# Testing scope function that calls a promise with Jasmine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, deferred

I'm writing tests for a scope function that calls a Promise and I'm trying to have access to some scope properties that are setted after the promise resolve.

This is basically my controller function:

```
$scope.submitNewForm = function (){
    Service.createUser($scope.user).then(function(result){
        if (result){
            $scope.message = 'success';
        } else {
            $scope.message = 'error';
        }
        $scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

What I pretty much want to test is if, after calling the scope function, my `$scope.message` is setted.

So far I have made some tests using `$q.defer()` but had no success

```
beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _Service_, $q) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    Service= _Service_;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    UserController= $controller('UserController', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should call Service.createUser and set a message', function(){
    spyOn(Service, 'createUser').and.callFake(function () {
        return deferred.promise;
    });
    scope.submitNewForm();
    scope.$digest();
    expect(scope.message).toBeDefined();
});
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

Well you might be getting an error of this sort on running the test.

[image: Error on running the test]

Well that's because you've simply returned a `promise` from the `spy` that you created on `Service`'s `createUser` method.

What you can do to fix it?
Just do a `deferred.reject` or `deferred.resolve` inside that `spy` and you'll get `scope.message` to be defined. Something like this:

```
spyOn(Service, 'createUser').and.callFake(function () {
    deferred.resolve('success');
    return deferred.promise;
});
```

Also there's one more thing I'd like to suggest. You should keep all your spies inside the `beforeEach` block where you inject the service and Mock the `controller` object. That way they would be reusable.

**UPDATE:**
To apply changes to the scope, you can do something like this:

```
it('should call Service.createUser and set a message', function(){
    scope.submitNewForm();
    scope.$$postDigest(function(){
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.message).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Not sure if this will work but this is what is generally done.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Siddharth. I'm now getting a `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress` and thats probably because I call `$scope.$apply()` inside my Promise callback, when I get rid of this it works. But I need it to apply the changes in my view. Any thoughts?

Comment: @adolfosrs, please mark as answer if this fixed your issue.